# How to extract data from a pandas dataframe based upon values of other columns?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have a df=

```
A= 
[period store  item
1        32     'A'
1        34     'A'
1        32     'B'
1        34     'B'
2        42     'X'
2        44     'X'
2        42     'Y'
2        44     'Y']
```

I want to find all the stores for an item in that period
preferably in a dictionary like this:

```
dicta = {1: {'A': (32, 34),'B': (32, 34)}, 2: {'X': (42, 44),'Y': (42, 44)}}
```

EDIT For @JEZRAEL

```
Actual df
       RTYPE  PERIOD_ID  STORE_ID                            MKT MTYPE  RGROUP  RZF  RXF
0        MKT        317     13178                      Kiosks_11  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
1        MKT        306     11437                      Kiosks_11  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
2        MKT        306     12236                      Kiosks_11  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
3        MKT        312     11024                      Kiosks_11  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
4        MKT        307     13010                      Kiosks_11  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
5        MKT        307     12723                      Kiosks_11  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
6        MKT        306     14218                      Kiosks_11  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
7        MKT        306     13547                      Kiosks_11  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
8        MKT        316     12396                      Kiosks_11  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
9        MKT        306     10778                      Cafes_638  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
10       MKT        317     11230                      Kiosks_11  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
11       MKT        315     13630                      Kiosks_11  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
12       MKT        314     14113                        Bars_13  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
13       MKT        314     12089                      Kiosks_11  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Here, PERIOD_ID AND STORE_ID and MKT are periods,stores and items respectively.
The edit suggested by @jezrael is returning me this for the above df.

```
d1={306L: (8207L, 8209L .... 8210L, 8211L),307L:( 8215L, 8219L ... 8233L, 8235L), 308: (8238L, 8239L....8244L, 8252L) ..k:(v) ..}
```

(Note: Edited to make it look small as the original dictionary is huge)

For the sample data it is working fine as expected but for this dataframe it isnt.

Edit for @jezrael as a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

df=

```
   RTYPE  PERIOD_ID    STORE_ID                       MKT MTYPE  RGROUP  RZF  RXF
0    MKT   20171411  3102300001  PM KA+PM PROV+SMKT+PETRO  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
1    MKT   20171411  3102300002  PM KA+PM PROV+SMKT+PETRO  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
2    MKT   20171411  3104001193              PM Provision  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
3    MKT   20171411  3104001193  PM KA+PM PROV+SMKT+PETRO  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
4    MKT   20171411  3104001193    Provision including MM  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
5    MKT   20171411  3104001641              PM Provision  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
6    MKT   20171411  3104001641  PM KA+PM PROV+SMKT+PETRO  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
7    MKT   20171411  3104001641    Provision including MM  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
8    MKT   20171411  3104001682              PM Provision  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
9    MKT   20171411  3104001682  PM KA+PM PROV+SMKT+PETRO  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
10   MKT   20171411  3104001682    Provision including MM  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
11   MKT   20171412  3104001682                   Alcohol  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
12   MKT   20171412  3104001682                      Fish  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
13   MKT   20171412  3104001684                   Alcohol  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
14   MKT   20171412  3104001684                      Fish  CELL     NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Current Ouput as per @jezraels code

```
{20171411L: ('Provision including MM', 'PM Provision', 'PM KA+PM PROV+SMKT+PETRO'), 20171412L: ('Fish', 'Alcohol')}
```

Expected Output :

```
{20171411L: ('Provision including MM', 'PM Provision'), 20171412L: ('Fish', 'Alcohol')}
```

For Period **20171411L**, **'Provision including MM', 'PM Provision'** MKT's are duplicate because they have the same set of store_ids whereas for period 
**20171412L** , 'Fish', 'Alcohol' MKT's are duplicate because they have the same set of store_ids.

I am new to Pandas but have some basic knowledge about Python.
Really not sure how  I can achieve this.
Any help will be great.

Comment: `{p: g.groupby('item')['store'].apply(tuple).to_dict() for p, g in df.groupby('period')}`

Answer (score 1):

Create `MultiIndex Series` and in dictionary comprehension create nested dictionary:

```
s = df.groupby(['period','item'])['store'].apply(tuple)

d = {level: s.xs(level).to_dict() for level in s.index.levels[0]}
print (d)
{1: {'A': (32, 34), 'B': (32, 34)}, 2: {'X': (42, 44), 'Y': (42, 44)}}
```

EDIT: You can grouping by `period` and convert `item` to sets and then to tuples:

```
d1 = {k:tuple(set(v)) for k, v in df.groupby('period')['item']}
print (d1)
{1: ('A', 'B'), 2: ('X', 'Y')}

d1 = df.groupby('period')['item'].apply(lambda x: tuple(set(x))).to_dict()
print (d1)
{1: ('A', 'B'), 2: ('X', 'Y')}
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael , Can you help me with one more thing, in the same dataframe A in the question I need to find the duplicates based upon this, if the set of stores for an item wrt to the periods is exactly the same then those items are duplicates. For ex: A,B are duplicates because they have the same stores in Period 1 and similarly X,Y are duplicates for Period 2. So in the end I am expecting an Output like this, dictout={1:(A,B),2:(X,Y)}. Can you please help?

Comment: Thanks but the edit you suggested is returning a unique set of items for that period , I needed a dictionary of Periods and Items which are duplicates for that period. Condition for being duplicates: if the set of stores for an item with respect to the periods is exactly the same as any other item in the same period then both of those items are duplicates. So in the given example A,B and X,Y are duplicates for Periods 1 and 2 respectively as they have the same stores.

Comment: @thebigshaikh - Sure, give me a sec.

Comment: @thebigshaikh - Can you test `df1 = df[df.duplicated(['period','item'], keep=False)]
d1 = {k:tuple(set(v)) for k, v in df1.groupby('period')['item']}` ?

Comment: Explanatio - `df1` filter only duplicates rows per `period` and `item`, unique are removed

Comment: Hi @jezrael, Thanks this works for the given example, but my actual df is slightly different and its returning some different OP. I'll add some part of the actual df in the  question, Can you please tell me why its returning a different output and how to fix it? I know I am asking a lot but this is something really urgent and very new to me thus I dont have the enough time and knowledge to do myself.

Comment: @thebigshaikh - `but my actual df is slightly different` - Can you explain more? What is different like your input data in question?

Comment: @thebigshaikh - ok, so can you add to question what is now output from my solution and what is expcted output from sample data?

Comment: Yes just a second.

Comment: Done, added it above.

Comment: @thebigshaikh - Super, so what is wrong? Need remove `L` ? Or something else?

Comment: Shouldn't the list of duplicates MKT/ITEMS be printed wrt the PERIODS, What I see it is printing this `d1={306L: (8207L, 8209L .... 8210L, 8211L),..}`. I expected the output to be like `d1={306L:(Kiosks_11,Bars_13) , .. }` . Note: I have added Kiosks_11 and Bars_13 just for explanatory purpose, they may or may not be duplicates.

Comment: @thebigshaikh - Can you check `df1 = df[df.duplicated(['PERIOD_ID','item'], keep=False)]
d1 = {k:tuple(set(v)) for k, v in df.groupby('PERIOD_ID')['MKT']}` ?

Comment: This is returning the unique set of MKT for every period and not the duplicate MKT for every period, for all periods the set of MKTS is the same in the op by the above piece of code.

Comment: @thebigshaikh - Can you change sample data for 5-8 rows only with expceted output - [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry for bothering. any idea how to implement it?

Comment: @thebigshaikh - 
Really complicated :(

Comment: hmm,  I know :/ Any idea if we could get it done using this type of dictionary `dicta = {1: {'A': (32, 34),'B': (32, 34)}, 2: {'X': (42, 44),'Y': (42, 44)}}` , if we could some how iterate through all the inner values and then compare them, although it will be very costly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do with a dict comprehension:

```
dicta = {p: g.groupby('item')['store'].apply(tuple).to_dict()
         for p, g in df.groupby('period')}
```

[out]

```
{1: {"'A'": (32, 34), "'B'": (32, 34)}, 2: {"'X'": (42, 44), "'Y'": (42, 44)}}
```

Comment: Hi @Chris A, Can you help me with one more thing, in the same dataframe A in the question I need to find the duplicates based upon this, if the set of stores for an item wrt to the periods is exactly the same then those items are duplicates. For ex: A,B are duplicates because they have the same stores in Period 1 and similarly X,Y are duplicates for Period 2. So in the end I am expecting an Output like this, dictout={1:(A,B),2:(X,Y)}. Can you please help?